# Syntax Error in Solidity Code: Found private Expected semicolon

Tags: solidity

I am trying to compile the following code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.8.0;
contract AddService{
   uint private _count;
   mapping(address=>bool) private _adders;
   function addByOne() public {
      require(_adders[msg.sender] == false, "You have added already");
      //Count
      _count++;
      //Call the callback function of the account
      AdderInterface adder = AdderInterface(msg.sender);
      adder.notify();
      //Add address to called collection
      _adders[msg.sender] = true;
   }
}

contract AdderInterface{
   function notify() public;
}

contract BadAdder is AdderInterface{
   AddService private _addService = //...;
   uint private _calls;
   //Callback
   function notify() public{
      if(_calls > 5){
         return;
      }
      _calls++;
      //Attention !!!!!!
      _addService.addByOne();
   }
   function doAdd() public{
      _addService.addByOne();
   }
}
```

The error is given below:

> > solc AddService.sol AddService.sol:25:9: Error: Expected ';' but got 'private'    uint private _calls;
> > ^-----^

Comment: Get rid of `= //...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The // comment on the line ... will also mask the end-of-statement character.
You need to either assign a value to the variable, or leave the pure specification unassigned:

```
   AddService private _addService=AddService(0x00) ;
```

or

```
AddService private _addService;
```